# How to restrict loading of an image in iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, image, iframe

I made a simple website with an iframe embed in the code. That iframe loads everything. I want to restrict a particular image which is an advertisement to load inside that iframe.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want the image to _only load_ if it's an an `<iframe>` - or do you want the image to _not load_ if it's in an `<iframe>`?

Comment: _"That iframe loads everything"_ - what **exactly** do you mean by this?

Comment: I dont want that specific image to load if its in an iframe. I have the src of that image from where it is loading in the iframe.

Comment: By "that iframe loads everything", i mean that it loads everything from the source web page. I want to filter out a certain ad image from the iframe.

Comment: If it's your own website, then you can set a Content Security Policy (CSP) on that specific image resource that prohibits browsers from loading it into an iframe.

Comment: The iframe src is not my own website. It's cross origin.

Comment: Then what you're asking is impossible: web-pages have no control over the content of cross-origin iframes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.